# Can I make changes to provisional patent once filed?

Tags: provisional-application

I do understand that provisional patent has one year grace period.

Am I able to add important points within this one year grace period (Ex: after 1 month) and file the non provisional patent in the last day of grace period?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No but kinda yes.

You cannot change the provisional patent once filed, but there are two other ways to achieve the same.

You can file another provisional and claim priority to both when filing the non provisional and get both priority dates, effectively having different priority dates for different claims in the non provisional.

Alternatively you can add the new information to the non provisional (you can file that earlier, too) and then have the priority of the prov. for whats in there and the priority of the non prov. for the rest.